# JavaScript while loop not behaving due to setState not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, while-loop

```
dealerTwisted = () => {
    console.log(this.state.dealersOverallTotal, 'total on entry');
    let looping = true;
    while(looping){
      console.log(this.state.dealersOverallTotal,'same');
      if(this.state.dealersOverallTotal < 17){
        this.deal2Dealer();
        let dealersDeck = this.state.dealersDeck;
        let newDealersDeckTotal = [];
        for (var i=0; i < dealersDeck.length; i++){
          newDealersDeckTotal.push(dealersDeck[i].rankValue)
        }
        let total = newDealersDeckTotal.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a + b;
        },
        0);
        console.log(total, 'tot');
        this.setState({ dealersOverallTotal: total }, () => console.log(this.state.dealersOverallTotal));
      }
```

the total console.log is doing the correct thing whereas the callback function is not updating dealersOverallTotal to the new value of total.
e.g.
total will log: 4, 15, 19 etc on every loop
this.state.dealersOverallTotal will log: 12, 12, 12 etc on every loop
it should be in sync with total as I have set its state to be the same as total

can anyone see why it is not updating? (I tried putting it in a callback to no avail)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook team wrote a nice [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for React ;)

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>   **There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.**

I don't really know why did you do this loop, but it's not the good way to doing this.

Answer (score 0):

setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

But state is updated as soon control goes to render() function:

```
var storeState;
    inXYZ()
    {
      this.setState({ dealersOverallTotal: total })
      //no state update
      console.log('state is updated',this.state.dealersOverallTotal)
    }

    render()
    {
     //updated over here
      storeState=this.state.dealersOverallTotal;
     console.log('state is updated',this.state.dealersOverallTotal)
    }
```

Comment: but I need it to change in my loop as I need it to continue in the loop till it reaches the else block

Comment: As soon as setState is fired, control will go to render and there you can set a global variable and use it anywhere, please see the updated answer.

Comment: I think it is dangerous to setstate without the setState method, no?

Comment: i didn't get you brother.

Comment: you updated state in the render() like so: ` storeState=this.state.dealersOverallTotal;` that is different to `this.setState({dealersOverallTotal: something})`

Comment: I did not update the state inside render() what i did is just assign state to a global variable.

Comment: I am trying to avoid globals too as they are bad practice but thanks

Comment: you want another approch ?